# How does nested function in an event handler receive the event object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How does the nested function inside `handleClick2` get the `e` object, when i am only passing the `input` object ?
Like how is the object `e` available for the scope of the nested function ? Does this have anything to do with **Lexical Environment** ?

```
  handleClick2 = (input) => (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [input]: e.target.value
    });
  };

render() {
        return (
              <button onClick={this.handleClick2('item')}>
                Confirm
              </button>
 
        );}
```

And how do i generate valid parameters for the `handleClick2` function as a return value from another function ?
For example:

```
  handleClick2 = (input) => (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [input]: e.target.value
    });
  };

handleClick1 = input => e => {
    // Mutate input and e 
    return handleClick2 with mutated input and e as parameters.

}

render() {
        return (
              <button onClick={this.handleClick1('item')}>
                Confirm
              </button>
 
        );}
```

Comment: @Andy his code is correct as it is if OP plans on using the same handler on different buttons with different `input`s

Comment: There is only one button in the code. What's the point in a closure?

Answer (score 2):

Funny, you get it working, you are wondering why right ?

Ok, let's do it slowly.

```
  handleClick = input => {
    return e => {
      this.setState(...}
    }
  }
```

The first invoke `handleClick(input)` is only returning a function. This function accepts `e` as input argument. And based on `button` interface, `onClick` is an event handler which is `e => {}`. Therefore it works.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little unclear what your code is meant to be doing since you've left a lot out.

Ideally you should be updating state when the input changes, and then doing something with that state when the button is clicked.

```js
const { Component } = React;

class Example extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { input: '' };
  }

  handleInput = (e) => {
    this.setState({ input: e.target.value });
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    console.log(this.state.input);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input onChange={this.handleInput} value={this.state.input} />
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click me</button>
      </div>
    );
  }

};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Or the shorter functional component way:

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example() {

  const [ input, setInput ] = useState('');

  function handleInput(e) {
    setInput(e.target.value);
  }

  function handleClick() {
    console.log(input);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={handleInput} value={input} />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When the `<button>` gets clicked it calls whatever function that you have passed in the `onClick` argument with the created `Event` as the argument. In this case the function is this lambda:

```
(e) => {
  this.setState({
    input]: e.target.value
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass the input argument at the moment the button is *created*. This call returns a *function*, which is the actual handler. It is this one:

```
(e) => {
  this.setState({
    [input]: e.target.value
  });
};
```

*That* function will only get called when the button is *clicked*, and it will get `e` as argument at that time, but it will also have access to `input`, which `handleClick` closes over.